# How do I convert DataFrame column of type "string" to "float" using .replace?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion

In my DataFrame, the "Value_String" column consists of strings that are either:

- number-like strings starting with dollar sign, and thousands are separated by a comma, [e.g. $1,000]
- "None"

Therefore, I tried to create a new column and convert the string to float with the following lambda function:

```
to_replace = '$,'

df['Value_Float'] = df[df['Value_String'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'None' 
else float(x.replace(y, '')) for y in to_replace)]
```

This actually generates a "TypeError: 'generator' object is not callable".

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numpy `where` method is very helpful for conditionally updating values.  In this case where the value is not 'None' we will use the replace function.  However since `str.replace` uses regex by default, we need to change the pattern to a literal dollar sign OR a comma

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value_String':["$1,000","None"]})
df['Value_String'] = np.where(df['Value_String']!='None', df['Value_String'].str.replace('\$|,',''), df['Value_String'])
print(df)
```

Output

```
  Value_String
0         1000
1         None
```

Comment: Thank you, indeed, the np.where method could reallly do the job.
Meanwhile. I tried again with the lambda function and it actually worked. I would still prefer to have all characters to replace in one single string as for my original question, any suggestion for that? 
    df_'Value_Float'] = df[Value'_String].apply(lambda x: 0 if x == 'None' else 
    float(x.replace('$', '').replace(',', '')))